# Sed regex - include original matching

Tags: sed

INPUT:

```
dsfgsdf8gfsd
2011.06.26. v
iudsfg98sdfg
sosdufgsdfg
2011.06.27. h
8xdofguiosdfg
jdasfhasd89fa
2011.06.28. k
ydsfgsdgsdg
dsfgdsfzfszgh
2011.06.29. sze
ds9fgisdfgsdfg
asdfasdfasddf
2011.06.30. cs
dsg789sdiofgsdg
dsfig89dsfgds
2011.07.01. p
sd9fg8sdgsdg
sdlfjgsd89öfgxcbv
dsglsd9gcxbv
dsflgjsdlfgfsdg
sdfsdfgdxfgxc
2011.07.02. szo
cvbdsgfsd
2011.07.03. v
dfgsdfgsd
2011.07.04. h
sdfgsdfgsdg
```

How can I get this OUTPUT with e.g.: sed? (or Perl?)

```
2011.06.26. v
iudsfg98sdfg
sosdufgsdfg
----------
2011.06.27. h
8xdofguiosdfg
jdasfhasd89fa
----------
2011.06.28. k
ydsfgsdgsdg
dsfgdsfzfszgh
----------
2011.06.29. sze
ds9fgisdfgsdfg
asdfasdfasddf
----------
2011.06.30. cs
dsg789sdiofgsdg
dsfig89dsfgds
----------
2011.07.01. p
sd9fg8sdgsdg
sdlfjgsd89öfgxcbv
dsglsd9gcxbv
dsflgjsdlfgfsdg
sdfsdfgdxfgxc
----------
2011.07.02. szo
cvbdsgfsd
----------
2011.07.03. v
dfgsdfgsd
----------
2011.07.04. h
sdfgsdfgsdg
```

So I want to swap the:

```
2011.06.26. v
```

AND

```
2011.06.27. h
```

etc. to this:

```
----------
2011.06.26. v
```

AND

```
----------
2011.06.27. h
```

I already tried (don't laugh :D ):

```
sed "s/[0-9]\{4\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\.[0-9]\{2\}\. /WTF/g"
```

But I don't know how to match "h, k, sze, cs, p, szo, v" in sed, and I don't know how can I put the matched things to the "WTF" (in .../WTF/g")

Has anyone any idea? :\

Thank you!

Comment: Does it actually need to be `sed`? For some reason people have a desperate need to use sed to mess with multiple lines at once or insert multiple lines; there are better tools for stuff like that

Comment: quotation: (or Perl?)

Comment: Well, does it actually need to be sed or perl, then. For example, this is trivial in awk: `awk '/pattern/ {print "--------"; print}'`

Comment: omg... :D of course :D thx..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A starting point is this sed line:

```
$ echo 2011.06.26. v | sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\. \([hv]\|sze\)\)$/----------\n\1/'
----------
2011.06.26. v
```

Since sed uses basic regular expression syntax (by default), you have to escape the `()|+` characters to get their special meaning (grouping, alternative, one or more). With `\1` you backreference the first group match.

Comment: Note that alternation (`\|`) and `\n` standing for a newline in replacement text work in GNU sed and some others, but they're not in POSIX.

Comment: @Gilles, POSIX regex don't include alternation?

Comment: Sadly, no, not the [basic regular expressions (BRE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) that sed uses. POSIX BREs only support `[…]` character classes, `.`, `*` repetition, `^$` anchors, and `\{…\}` repetition, plus `\(…\)` subexpressions and `\N` backreferences. `\?`, `\+` and `\|` are common but not universal extensions. POSIX [Extended regular expressions (ERE)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), such as used by awk, support the usual operators `()[].?*+{}|`.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution using `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9]\{4\}\.[01][0-9]\.[0123][0-9]\./,${:a;N;$!ba;{s/\([0-9]\{4\}\.[01][0-9]\.[0123][0-9]\.\)/--------------\n\1/g;p}}'
```

The disadvantage is that the date has to be matched twice. Maybe there's another (better) solution.
The output is exactly as you expect in your example.

Answer (score 0):

In other words you want to insert the line `----------` before every line that contains a YYYY.MM.DD date followed by a space and a bunch of lowercase letters.
There are several ways to do this. You can use the insert command (`i`):

```
sed -e '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]*$/ i \
----------'
```

Or you can replace the empty string at the beginning of the line by a newline.

```
sed -e '/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]*$/ s/^/----------\
'
```

Or you can use `&` in the replacement text of an `s` command to stand for the matched pattern.

```
sed -e 's/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9] [a-z][a-z]*$/----------\
&'
```

Some `sed` implementations allow you to write `\n` instead of backslash-newline in the replacement text, but on others `\n` prints `\n` or `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use awk instead

`awk ' /[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\. / { print "---------------------\n" $0 ; continue } /^/ { print $0 } ' <"INPUTFILE"  >"OUTPUTFILE"`

basically it works in 2 steps:

step1: `/[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\. / { print "---------------------\n" $0 ; continue }`

means: if it maches /4digits.2digits.2digits. / then print "---...--\n" followed by the matching line, and loop on the next line (= "continue").

step2: `/^/ { print $0 }`

means: if we didn't match the above, then for all other lines (ie, matching a beginning of line, so even an empty line gets matched), just print that line.